# Call javascript function on page load in R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I added references to css and javascript files as follows:

```
  tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="rtp.css"),
  tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "rtp.js"),
```

How do I make a call to a javascript function defined in "rtp.js"?
 I have tried

```
tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "myfunction()")
```

(which does not work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `JS()` function from `htmlwidgets` package (I think it comes by default with `shiny`)

To add a custom function executing at the start of the application:

```
tags$script(JS('alert("initialized!")'))

tags$script(JS('myfunction()'))
```

If `myfunction()` resides in an external file, first import it and the execute:

```
tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "rtp.js"),
tags$script(JS('myfunction())'))
```

Comment: Thanks @GGamba, sorry I'm a complete JS newbie. I added JS('myfunction()') to my code, but shiny prints the expression rather than calling the function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add a bit of context, what are you trying to accomplish with the js function()?

Comment: Thank you, that it is clearer now. Though still not working even with tags$script(JS('myfunction()')). I'm not sure what lines 2-5 on your code do. It seems that you are defining a function. I am trying to use myfunction(), which is defined within rtp.js. It adds a widget on mobile devices to add to [home screen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen). @GGamba

Answer (score 1):

The `src="foo"` argument means to get the source for your script from a file named `foo`. If you have inline code instead, then provide an *unnamed* argument to `tags$script`:

```
tags$script(type="text/javascript", "myfunction()")

# <script type="text/javascript">myfunction()</script>
```