# To enable and disable sidebar toggle button using a action button

Tags: shiny, togglebutton, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am looking for a code snippet using which, I can enable/disable sidebar toggle button in shinydashboard header.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs()
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse") # Hide Side Bar
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Let me know if anybody can help???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution to this...If someone is stuck with same problem, can refer to below solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar( tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML(#code for hiding sidebar tabs 
        "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('manipulateMenuItem1', function(message)
        {
        var aNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

        for (var i = 0; i < aNodeList.length; i++) 
        {
        if(aNodeList[i].getAttribute('data-toggle') == message.toggle && aNodeList[i].getAttribute('role') == message.role) 
        {
        if(message.action == 'hide')
        {
        aNodeList[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
        } 
        else 
        {
        aNodeList[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
        };
        };
        }
        });"
                                                      )
    )
    )
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("h1","Hide toggle"),
    actionButton("h2","Show toggle")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$h1,{
     session$sendCustomMessage(type = "manipulateMenuItem1", message = list(action = "hide",toggle = "offcanvas", role = "button"))
    })
  observeEvent(input$h2,{
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "manipulateMenuItem1", message = list(action = "show",toggle = "offcanvas", role = "button"))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use the `shinyjs` package, you can show or hide the sidebar toggle with a quick line of JavaScript.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("hide","Hide toggle"),
    actionButton("show","Show toggle")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$hide,{
    shinyjs::runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';")
  })
  observeEvent(input$show,{
    shinyjs::runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The JavaScript itself just refers to the first element with class `sidebar-toggle` (i.e. the menu button), and toggles the visibility depending on which button the user presses.