# navbar of shiny app interferes with navbar of rmarkdown webpage

Tags: html, r, iframe, shiny, r-markdown

I am starting a webpage for my lab, and among the products we have
developed is a shiny app to check the global climate change.

Here is the [website](http://www.ecoinformatica.net/GCMcompareR.html) in that page and this is how the app looks [standalone](http://admin.ecoinformatica.net/shiny/rstudio/sample-apps/GCM/) as you can see in the menu there are three options that are not seen in the website, in the intro tab, the *Intro*, *Workflow*, *About* and *Changelog* should be visible

### Website yaml

I made a webpage using classic rmarkdown website building, so my webpage yaml looks like this:

```
name: "Sitio web de ecoinformática del laboratorio Marquet"
navbar:
  title: "Ecoinformática"
  left:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
    - text: "Sobre nosotros"
      href: about.html
    - text: "GCM compareR app"
      href: GCMcompareR.html
    - text: Docencia
      icon: fa-gear
      menu:
      - text: Ecología BIO231c 
      - text: Modulo 1.1
        href: Modulo1.1.html
      - text: Modulo 1.2
        href: Modulo1.2.html
    - text: RPackages
      icon: fa-gear
      menu:
      - text: RPackages
      - text: NetworkExtinction
        href: VignetteNetworkExt.html
output_dir: "."
output:
  html_document:
    theme: cosmo
    highlight: textmate
    include:
    css: styles.css
```

### Actual app Rmd

And in the tab of GCM compareR app I have the following:

````
---
title: ""
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE) 
```

<iframe src="http://admin.ecoinformatica.net/shiny/rstudio/sample-apps/GCM/"style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"">
````

### Solutions that might work but cant figure out

- Add a padding on the top to prevent both navbars to generate conflicts
- Remove the navbar of the website when I go to the app webpage
- Make the navbar of de website "deployable", so that it only appears when I move the cursor to the edge of the webpage
- change the navbar of the webpage to the left.

### What I have tried:

#### Changing the borders :

```
<iframe src="http://admin.ecoinformatica.net/shiny/rstudio/sample-apps/GCM/"style="border: 100; position:absolute; top:100; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"">
```

#### make the app responsive

```
<div class="resp-container">
    <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="http://admin.ecoinformatica.net/shiny/rstudio/sample-apps/GCM/" style="border: 100; position:absolute; top:100; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"">
```

#### use include_app

````
```{r}
knitr::include_app("http://admin.ecoinformatica.net/shiny/rstudio/sample-apps/GCM/", height = "600px")
```
````

Which kind of works, but I can't fix the width

Any help would be welcome

Comment: I cannot see these options on either of those links. I can see the very bottom of the options on both.

Comment: You could easily pad the Shiny Nav-bar so that it hangs low enough that it is fully visible underneath the website nav-bar. That is the easy solution, the harder but more interesting solution is the cursor triggered nav-bar.

Comment: Considering I cannot see the options on either page, and I am guessing you can, this may be browser/monitor dependent problem meaning the cursor activated nav-bar would be a much more robust solution.

Comment: I think so to @Chabo, any Idea how to do it?

Comment: The best shot at making that happen would be with `toggle` from the shinyjs function. See here https://deanattali.com/2015/04/23/shinyjs-r-package/

Comment: The second answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939346/hide-main-header-toggle-in-r-shiny-app shows how we could go about toggling non-shiny ui elements (HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shiny app navbar can be moved down by a few pixels by tweaking the height and top options of the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://admin.ecoinformatica.net/shiny/rstudio/sample-apps/GCM/"style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:5%; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:95%"">
</iframe>
```